# Declare a static function but implement it without the 'static' keyword in C?

Tags: c, static, declaration, implementation, forward-declaration

Is it fine to write a `forward declaration` of a function with a `static` keyword but implemet it later in the file without the `static` keyword?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */

static void func();

int main()
{
    func();

    return(0);
}

void func()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

It compiles and runs without any errors, but would `func` be a `static` function or not and why?

Comment: It is static, because you already declared it so.

Comment: is it fine to write it down like that? to declare the function with a specific keyword and then implement it without it? Is it accepted?

Comment: The forward declaration should be `static void func(void);` because the function has no parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.2.2 5 says a function declaration without a storage-class specifier (such as `extern` or `static`) is the same as using `extern`:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`…

C 2018 6.2.2 4 says a declaration with `extern` after a declaration with `static` that is visible<sup>1</sup> uses the internal linkage established by the `static`:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.

So the behavior is defined to use internal linkage, and I am fairly confident there is nothing in the C standard that overrides this.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> An earlier declaration of a function declared at file scope could be hidden by a declaration of the same identifier in block scope. Then the earlier declaration would not be visible in that block.